# Why Does Excel ReCalc on Open

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to determine what causes a workbook to calculate when opening.  I know the basics:

- volatile formulas
- closing workbook without calculating

I have a 15MB workbook that we have used for years and it never used to calculate on open.  We have it saved as an `xlsb`. If I save it as an `xlsx` then it no longer calculates on open.  If after saving it as an `xlsx` I save it back to a `xlsb` it still recalculates.  Saving it as an `xlsm` also requires recalculating.  I have cleared all conditional formatting from every sheet as well as data validation to insure those don't have volatile formulas and that doesn't help.  There are a little over 100 sheets and I have went through deleting them 10 at a time and each time they still keep recalculating.  Our model was always a `xlsb`, so does anyone know what could cause this?

I know that I can prevent the workbook from calculating by setting calculations to manual, but that just delays the calculation.  If a workbook is calculated when you save it, then it shouldn't recalculate on open (unless there are volatile formulas).

Comment: I know how to prevent it from running, but that doesn't solve the issue.  It just delays the calculation until you turn it back on.  I want to know why Excel thinks it needs to recalculate.  If the workbook is calculated prior to saving then it shouldn't need it when opening.  This model always used to work that way, and all my other models work that way now as well.

Comment: Are there links to other sheets or workbooks?

Comment: No I made sure there wasn't by clearing all named ranges, conditional formatting, and data validation.  Checked the links button in the review tab, and searched the workbook for .xl and \\ both returned no results.  Also, it doesn't recalc when saved as a xlsx so I don't believe that is the issue

Comment: Isn't this... default behavior? Doesn't setting it to manual calculation prevent it from recalculating after saving, closing, and reopening?

Comment: After first looking at this yesterday, I was digging and saw some forum posts indicating that the base `Personal` file was tied to autocalculate or manual.  When opening an xlsb file, if your Personal file isn't `Personal.xlsb`, it will not retain the change from autocalculate to manual.  Note that there have been similar discussions of the inverse, where files are all opening as Manual when xlsb.  [This article](https://www.excelandaccess.com/excel-retains-manual-calculation/) is the most concise item I have found on the issue, rather than scattered posts..

Comment: @TylerH, no the default isn't to auto calculate if everything was calculated when it saved.  This only started happening a few months back

Comment: Did you check the VB editor possibly VBA code for Workbook_Open Event has been kept there !!